# Azure container services and Application gateway

Tags: azure, networking, kubernetes

I connected an Application Gateway as a frontend for the services in the kubernetes cluster. I created a subnet on the `k8s-vnet-<id>` with address space `10.0.0.0/29` and connected the Application Gateway to that subnet.

I followed instrucions from https://fizzylogic.nl/2017/06/16/how-to-connect-azure-api-management-to-your-kubernetes-cluster/

When I try to scale the `ContainerServices` I get the following error:

```
Operation name: Write VirtualNetworks
Error code: InUseSubnetCannotBeDeleted
Message: 
Subnet api-gateway-subnet is in use by /subscriptions/cdf495e8-6232-4a61-a661-716fec93f8b5/resourceGroups/KuberGoPlay/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/ngaz-appgw-play/gatewayIPConfigurations/appGatewayIpConfig and cannot be deleted.
```

Why is the container service trying to delete the subnet when it scales?
Or am I connecting the Application Gateway the wrong way ?

/Martin

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the container service trying to delete the subnet when it
>   scales?

When we try to scale up or scale down (update a resource) Azure container service, the request is processed by deleting and creating the resource.

> You may encounter this error when attempting to update a resource, but
>   the request is processed by deleting and creating the resource. Make
>   sure to specify all unchanged values.

More information about [InUseSubnetCannotBeDeleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/gl-es/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-common-deployment-errors), please refer to that link.

Here a article talk about how to use template to update resource, please refer to [it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/building-blocks/extending-templates/update-resource).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)